# multithreading in python - I want to pass in a dictionary as the args

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

I tried passing in a dictionary into a threading function

```
enemy_movement_thread = threading.Thread(target=enemy_movement, args= data)
enemy_movement_thread.start()
```

but an error occurred:

```
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryanc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ryanc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: enemy_movement() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given
```

Comment: So, `data` is either a list or a tuple with 7 items.  If your `enemy_movement` function expects that list as a single parameter, then you need  `threading.Thread(target=enemy_movement, args=[data])`.

Comment: Thank you very much!